# How do I scale a screenshot up and down and keep the quality?

Tags: resize, screenshot, microsoft-powerpoint

For an assignment I would like to show the steps that I took on my pc (with print screens) in PowerPoint. I will show these timeline print screens scaled down but when I upscale them back they become vague and unclear.

Is there a way when I enlarge them back at a larger size that they are of good quality again?

Comment: Can you post some screen shots showing how they have degraded?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately images do not retain quality if you decrease the scale. Best practice is to not amend the scale in the first place, and use the original unaltered images in your PP presentation, without scaling them in photoshop or whatever program you use.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing Images in Photoshop/Paint or any image editor but not In power point directly would reserve a good quality of the image  and not to be fuzzy.

Also to note That resizing images t lower resolutions like from 400px to 200px doesn't waste the quality but what is visible the other way around does waste.

Maybe you have a very high resolution Try The following:

1.Set your resolution at a smaller value like (1024x768) or (1366x768) (Best Solution) and take your shoots.

2.Try to focus on the important part of the shot , don't worry the human brain can tell the rest of the screen if he saw a known screen or a familiar one.